# Is $PX+X^{\rm T}P>0$ if $P$ is symmetric positive definite and all eigenvalues of $X$ have positive real parts?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric positive definite, and let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be such that all its eigenvalues are in the open right-half complex plane. Can we prove or disprove by counter-example that 
\begin{equation}
PX+X^{\rm T}P
\end{equation} 
is positive definite?

Thanks

Comment: what is exactly the "open right half" of the complex plane?

Comment: @Surb $\{x\in\mathbb{C}:{\rm Re~}x>0\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take 
$$
P=I,\quad X=\begin{bmatrix}1 & x\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
PX+X^TP=X+X^T=\begin{bmatrix}2 & x\\x & 2\end{bmatrix}=Q.
$$
If $\det Q=4-x^2<0$ then $Q$ is indefinite.